# Does every weapon have a unique equivalent?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout New Vegas there are many "unique" variants of normal weapons, for example the All-American is the unique Marksman Carbine and the Gobi Campaign Scout Rifle is the unique variant of the Sniper Rifle. My question is: is there a unique equivalent for every non-special weapon in the game? I've found many unique variants, but I'm wondering if one exists for every weapon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a list of all the weapons and their unique counterparts, taken from the [Fallout: New Vegas Weapons entry](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_weapons) on the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/). There are a couple of weapons that have more than one unique counterpart, and there are several weapons that have none. Note that some weapons are DLC exclusive, with at least one exclusive to pre-order.

## Handguns

- **.357 Magnum Revolver:** *Lucky*, *Police Pistol (DLC)*.
- **.44 Magnum Revolver:** *Mysterious Magnum*.
- **.45 Auto Pistol (DLC):** *A Light Shining In Darkness (DLC)*.
- **5.56mm Pistol:** *That Gun*.
- **9mm Pistol:** *Maria*.
- **10mm Pistol:** *Weathered 10mm Pistol (DLC/Preorder)*.
- **12.7mm Pistol:** *Li'l Devil (DLC)*.
- **Hunting Revolver:** *Ranger Sequoia*.
- **Silenced .22 Pistol:** None.

## Rifles

- **.44 Magnum Revolver:** *Mysterious Magnum*.
- **Anti-material Rifle:** None.
- **Assault Carbine:** None.
- **Automatic Rifle (DLC):** None.
- **Battle Rifle (DLC):** *This Machine*.
- **BB Gun:** *Abilene Kid LE BB Gun*.
- **Brush Gun:** *Medicine Stick (DLC)*.
- **Cowboy Repeater:** *La Longue Carbine*.
- **Hunting Rifle:** *Paciencia (DLC)*.
- **Light Machine Gun:** *Bozar (DLC)*.
- **Marksman Carbine:** *All-American*.
- **Service Rifle:** *Survivalist's Rifle (DLC)*.
- **Sniper Rifle:** *Gobi Campaign Scout Rifle*, **Christine's CoS Silencer Rifle (DLC)*.
- **Trail Carbine:** None.
- **Varmint Rifle:** *Rat Slayer*.

## Sub Machine Guns

- **.45 Auto Sub Machine Gun:** None.
- **10mm Sub Machine Gun:** *Sleepytime (DLC)*.
- **12.7mm Sub Machine Gun:** *Mysterious Magnum*.
- **9mm Sub Machine Gun:** *Vance's 9mm Sub Machine Gun*.
- **H&H Tools Nail Gun (DLC):** None.
- **Silenced .22 Sub Machine Gun:** None.

## Shotguns

- **Caravan Shotgun:** *Sturdy Caravan Shotgun (DLC/Preorder)*.
- **Hunting Shotgun:** *Dinner Bell*.
- **Lever-Action Shotgun:** None.
- **Riot Shotgun:** None.
- **Sawed-Off Shotgun:** *Big Boomer*.
- **Single Shotgun:** None.

## Heavy Weapons

- **K9000 Cyber Dog Gun (DLC):** *FIDO (DLC)*.
- **Minigun:** *CZ57 Avenger*.
- **Shoulder Mounted Machine Gun (DLC):** None.

## Energy Pistols

- **Flare Gun (DLC):** None.
- **Laser Pistol:** *Compliance Regulator (DLC)*, *Missing Laser Pistol*.
- **MF Hyperbreeder Alpha (DLC):** None.
- **Plasma Defender:** None.
- **Plasma Pistol:** None.
- **Pulse Gun:** None.
- **Recharger Pistol:** None.
- **Sonic Emitter - Gabriel's Bark (DLC)**:** None.
- **Sonic Emitter - Opera Singer (DLC):** None.
- **Sonic Emitter - Revelation (DLC):** None.
- **Sonic Emitter - Robo-Scorpion (DLC):** None.
- **Sonic Emitter - Tarantula (DLC):** None.
- **Additional Unique Energy Pistols:** *Alien Blaster*, *Euclid's C-Finder*.

## Energy Rifles

- **Gauss Rifle:** *YCS/186*.
- **Holorifle:** None.
- **LAER (DLC):** *Elijah's Advanced LAER (DLC)*.
- **Laser RCW:** None.
- **Laser Rifle:** *AER14 Laser Rifle*, *Van Graff Laser Rifle*.
- **Multiplas Rifle:** None.
- **Plasma Rifle:** *Van Graff Plasma Rifle*, *Q-35 Matter Modulator*.
- **Recharger Rifle:** None.
- **Tri-beam Laser Rifle:** None.

## Energy Heavy Weapons

- **Arc Welder (DLC):** None.
- **Flamer:** *Cleansing Flame (DLC).
- **Gatling Laser:** *Sprtel-Wood 9700 (DLC)*.
- **Heavy Incinerator:** None.
- **Incinerator:** None.
- **Plasma Caster:** *They Smitty Special (DLC)*.
- **Tesla Cannon:** *Elijah's Jury-Rigged Cannon (DLC)*, *Tesla-Beaton Prototype*.

## Launcher

- **25mm Grenade APW (DLC):** None.
- **Fat Man:** *Esther*.
- **Grenade Launcher:** None.
- **Grenade Machine Gun:** *Mercy*.
- **Grenade Rifle:** *Great Bear Grenade Rifle (DLC), *Mercenary's Grenade Rifle (DLC/Preorder)*, *Red Victory Grenade Rifle (DLC)*, *Thump-Thump*.
- **Missile Launcher:** *Annabelle*.
- **Red Glare (DLC):** None.

## Thrown Explosive

- **Dynamite:** None.
- **Fire Bomb (DLC):** None.
- **Flash Bang (DLC):** None.
- **Frag Grenade:** *Holy Frag Grenade*.
- **Incendiary Grenade:** None.
- **Long-Fuse Dynamite:** None.
- **MFC Grenade (DLC):** None.
- **Nuka-Grenade (DLC):** None.
- **Plasma Grenade:** None.
- **Pulse Grenade:** None.
- **Tin Grenade (DLC):** None.

## Placed Explosive

- **Bottlecap Mine:** None.
- **C-4 Plastic Explosive:** None.
- **Demolition Charge (DLC):** None.
- **Detonator:** None.
- **Fat Mine (DLC):** None.
- **Frag Mine:** None.
- **Gas Bomb (DLC):** None.
- **MFC Cluster (DLC):** None.
- **Plasma Mine:** None.
- **Powder Charge:** None.
- **Pulse Mine:** None.
- **Satchel Charge (DLC):** None.
- **Time Bomb:** None.
- **Time Bomb, High Yield (DLC):** None.

## Blade Melee

- **Blade Of The West:** None.
- **Bowie Knife (DLC):**, *Blood-Nap (DLC)*.
- **Bumper Sword:** *Blade Of The East*.
- **Chainsaw:** None.
- **Cleaver:** *Chopper*.
- **Combat Knife:** *Chance's Knife*.
- **Cosmic Knife (DLC):** None.
- **Cosmic Knife Clean (DLC):** None.
- **Cosmic Knife Super-Heated (DLC):** None.
- **Fire Axe:** *Knock-Knock*.
- **Hatchet:** None.
- **Katana (DLC):** None.
- **Knife:** None.
- **Knife Spear (DLC):** None.
- **Knife Spear Clean (DLC):** None.
- **Machete:** *Broad Machete (DLC)*, *Liberator*.
- **Machete Gladius:** None.
- **Proton Axe (DLC):** None.
- **Protonic Inversal Axe (DLC):** None.
- **Ripper:** None.
- **Shishkebab:** *Gehenna (DLC)*.
- **Straight Razor:** *Figaro*.
- **Switchblade:** None.
- **Thermic Lance:** None.

## Blunt Melee

- **9 Iron:** *Nephi's Golf Driver*.
- **Baseball Bat:** None.
- **Cattle Prod:** None.
- **Dress Cane:** None.
- **Lead Pipe:** *The Humble Cudgel*.
- **Nail Board:** *Old Glory (DLC)*.
- **Pool Cue:** None.
- **Police Baton:** None.
- **Rebar Club:** *Nuka Breaker (DLC)*.
- **Rolling Pin:** None.
- **Shovel:** None.
- **Super Sledge:** *Oh, Baby!*.
- **Tire Iron:** None.
- **War Club (DLC):** None.
- **Additional Unique Blunt Melee:** *X-2 Antenna (DLC)*.

## Thrown

- **Proton Throwing Axe (DLC):** None.
- **Protonic Inversal Throwing Axe (DLC):** None.
- **Throwing Hatchet:** None.
- **Throwing Knife:** None.
- **Throwing Knife Spear (DLC):** None.
- **Throwing Spear:** None.
- **Tomahawk (DLC):** None.

## Unarmed

- **Ballistic Fist:** *Two-Step Goodbye (DLC)*.
- **Bear Trap Fist (DLC):** None.
- **Bladed Gauntlet:** *Cram Opener*.
- **Boxing Gloves:** *Golden Gloves*.
- **Boxing Tape:** None.
- **Brass Knuckles:** None.
- **Displacer Glove:** *Pushy*.
- **Dog Tag Fist:** *Recompense Of The Fallen*.
- **Fist of Rawr/ Fist of North Rawr (DLC):** None.
- **Industrial Hand (DLC):** None.
- **Mantis Gauntlet:** *Embrace Of The Mantis King! (DLC)*.
- **Power Fist:** *Greased Lightning (DLC)*, *Salt-Upon-Wounds' Power Fist (DLC)*.
- **Saturnite Fist (DLC):** None.
- **Saturnite Fist Super-Heated (DLC):** None.
- **Scientist Glove (DLC):** *Dr. Klein's Glove (DLC)*, *Dr Mobius' Glove (DLC)*.
- **Corrosive Glove:** None.
- **Sterilizer Glove:** None.
- **Spiked Knuckles:** *Love And Hate*.
- **Yao Guai Gauntlet (DLC):** *She's Embrace (DLC)*.
- **Zap Glove:** *Paladin Toaster*.

Comment: Remember, players, if there is a particular unique on the list  you expect to be spending a lot of time with, stock pile the normal weapon. All unique weapons (apart from the Alien Blaster) can be repaired withe the normal counterpart.

The **Alien Blaster** is unique in that you can not repair it. You can not obtain more power cells for it, either, so save it for a tough fight. The Alien Blaster is often considered the best gun in the game, and guarantees a critical hit (1-shotting almost every enemy in the game).

Comment: As a short TL;DR: No

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete list of Weapons and Unique Weapons [over at the Fallout Wiki.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_weapons)

As you can see, there are a bunch of weapons without unique variants, such as (but not limited to), the Hatchet, Thermal Lance, Police Baton, Sledgehammer, Brass Knuckles, Incinerator, Recharger Rifle, Trail Carbine, Silenced .22 Guns, the Police Pistol...